# Error peer dependencies for @firebase/database in cloud functions using firebase-admin

Tags: node.js, firebase, firebase-admin

I have some functions that use the `firebase-admin` package.

I don't know exactly when, but at some point I started to get some npm WARNING's:

```
npm WARN @firebase/database@0.4.12 requires a peer of @firebase/app@0.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @firebase/database@0.4.12 requires a peer of @firebase/app-types@0.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN @firebase/database-types@0.4.2 requires a peer of @firebase/app-types@0.x but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
```

So in `firebase-admin`'s `package.json` file, there is:

```
"dependencies": {
    "@firebase/database": "^0.4.7",
    "@google-cloud/firestore": "^2.0.0",
    "@google-cloud/storage": "^3.0.2",
    "@types/node": "^8.0.53",
    "dicer": "^0.3.0",
    "jsonwebtoken": "8.1.0",
    "node-forge": "0.7.4"
  },
```

And in `@firebase/database`'s `package.json`, there is:

```
"peerDependencies": {
    "@firebase/app": "0.x",
    "@firebase/app-types": "0.x"
  },
```

But when I go to their NPM pages:

https://www.npmjs.com/package/@firebase/app
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@firebase/app-types

I see this:

> This package is not intended for direct usage, and should only be used via the officially supported firebase package.

**QUESTION:**

Am I supposed to install them or not?

Comment: What version of firebase-admin are you using?  Can you show the minimal code and package.json that gives you warnings so that anyone can copy it and reproduce the issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a known issue, and will be fixed in a future version of the JS SDK: https://github.com/firebase/firebase-js-sdk/pull/2082

It is safe to ignore the warnings.